# How can we write gtest for a method which calls a method of protected defined class member?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

```
// Memory.h

#include "Block.h"

namespace User{

class Memory
{
    
protected:
    Block block_instance;
    
public:
    BlockList* GetBlockList();
    
};

}
```

```
// Memory.cpp

#include "Memory.h"

namespace User{
const BlockList* Memory::GetBlockList()
{
    return block_instance.GetList();
}
}
```

I want to test GetBlockList from Memory class with gtest, but I suppose I need to use gmock to mocking Block Class. block_instance is protected variable and I suppose use EXPECT_CALL for its return value. How can we mock this scenario, how can we write test for it ?

I tried to define interface but I can't access to block_instance. I had build errors. I can not imagine how can I access to block_instance and test the return value of it in other method.

Comment: The answer is probably not, you should test Block in isolation before making it a member of memory. So you have proven Block is correct before integrating it. The only other option is to give Block an abstract baseclass and use dependency injection for Memory, so you can verify the Memory class will make all the correct calls on a mock for Block

Comment: `struct MemoryTestBuddy : Memory { /**/ };` and now your tests can access Memory's `block_instance` via MemoryTestBuddy.  Or bake in a test-hook `class Memory { friend struct TestBuddy; /*...*/ };`

Comment: @Eljay Nice shortcut for this case ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would expect something along these lines (with dependency injection)

```
// make abstract baseclasses for classes involved in unit tests
class BlockListItf
{
};

class BlockItf
{
public:
    virtual BlockListItf& GetList() = 0;
};

class Block :
    public BlockItf
{
    BlockListItf& GetList() override 
    {
        return m_list; // or something like this.
    }
};

// for your unit tests you can make mocks
// these can help you determine what Memory will be
// doing to a Block when it is being tested.
class BlockMock
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(BlockListItf&,GetList, (), (override));
};

// The memory class should no longer create a block itself
// but it must be injected (standard design for unit testability)
class Memory
{
public:
    // dependency injection
    // allows for runtime selection of a block implementation
    // either production code of a mock
    explicit Memory(BlockItf& block) : m_block{block} 
    {
    };


    // I prefer returning & when something cannot by design
    // be a nullptr. Again return an abstract baseclass
    // not an actual implementation
    const BlockListItf& Memory::GetBlockList()
    {
        return m_block_itf.GetList();
    }

protected:
    BlockItf& m_block_itf;
    
private:
    BlockListItf& m_blocklist;
};

// And then in unit testing use dependency injection

TEST_F(SomeUnitTest,construct)
{
    BlockMock block_mock;
    
    // todo write a function that will return a block list mock
    ON_CALL(factory, DoMakeTurtle).WillByDefault(Return(MakeBlockListMock())); 

    // setup call expectation
    EXPECT_CALL(block_mock, GetBlockList).Times(1);

    Memory memory(block_mock);
    auto& block_list = memory.GetBlockList();
    ASSERT(block_list.size() > 0 ); // or some other test you can think of

}
```